# Show realtime charts in SuperSet with Druid

Tags: druid, apache-superset

How I can do realtime charts in Superset over Druid?

I can select last day, but then it set the interval to 
"2019-06-02T00:00:00+00:00/2019-06-03T00:00:00+00:00".

Meaning from last day 00:00 to today 00:00, so I'm missing all current day data.

If I select last hour it set the interval to "2019-06-02T23:00:00+00:00/2019-06-03T00:00:00+00:00".

Again it takes the hour from 23 to midnight.

When checking "next hour" or "next day", it again calculates everything relative to 00:00.

I wish to see an ongoing chart on real-time data, last our or last day.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the trick, need to select from "today" to "tomorrow":
[image]